# How to store translates in MySQL to use join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains all translations of words:

```
CREATE TABLE `localtexts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Lang` char(2) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pe',
  `Text` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ShortText` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DbVersion` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

As example there is a table that refers to `localtexts`:

```
CREATE TABLE `composes` (
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table above has foreign key `Id` to `localtexts.Id`. And when I need to get word on English I do:

```
SELECT localtexts.text, 
       composes.status 
FROM composes 
LEFT JOIN localtexts ON composes.Id = localtexts.Id
WHERE localtexts.Lang = 'en'.
```

I'm concerned in performance this decision when there are a lot of tables for join with `localtexts`.

Comment: you are missing primary key´ys and indexes, where it isn't unique

Comment: It is a good idea to have `id autoincrement not null primary key` , so you could have a `guaranteed unique row identifier.`

Comment: Autoincrement where? There `localtexts.Id`?

Comment: @IvankaClerc every table is good to have its own `id autoincrement` . Something like [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8040b9627c1850651d0e866de1974687).

Comment: Show us the `PRIMARY KEY` and any indexes.

Comment: `composes.Id = localtexts.Id` if both table have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then why have 2 tables?  Move `status` into the other table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that adding the following index to the `localtexts` table would speed up the query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON localtexts (Lang, id, text);
```

This index covers the `WHERE` clause, join, and `SELECT`.

Comment: that is not enough

Comment: Maybe there is another way to approach this?

Comment: Your left join is actually pretty optimal, as the join condition can already just use the PK `id` column on `localtexts`.  My index does this, but also lets the other parts of the query be faster.

Comment: Lang, id, text is it unique index? or primary?

Comment: Just run the exact `CREATE INDEX` command as I have given it.